# laravel 5.4 forgot password

Tags: php, authentication, xampp, laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4
PHP 5.6
XAMPP localhost

I have set up a basic laravel app, I ran command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

to create the auth scaffolding

then ran command

```
php artisan migrate
```

to update the databases and create necessary tables

I am able to register users, log them in , and log out.
However none of the other authentication stuff works.

Here is the error I receive when I try
    localhost/password/email

```
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 176)
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 546)
at Router->findRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 525)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 511)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 176)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 151)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 54)
```

But the method not allowed thing makes no sense to me since my Router.php is this:

```
// Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 
'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')-
>name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 
'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')-
>name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 
'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

And my email.blade.php

```
...
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ 
route('password.email') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
...
```

Notice the method="POST"

And my web.php has the "Auth:routes();"

Can someone please help?

The docs online make it sound as if running php artisan make:auth is all you need for proper authentication flow, but what if your user forgets their password?

Another thing, laravel documentation reads:
    To get started, verify that your App\User model implements the 
    Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword contract.

Here is my model User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
use CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
$this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
}
```

Comment: what have you set as the root directory of XAMPP?

Comment: The standard C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite

Comment: your root needs to be the public directory inside the laravel project and then all your routes should start working properly

Answer (score 0):

When you "try" `localhost/password/email` you are calling the URL using GET. This route (`/password/email`) is registered as a POST route in your `router.php`, that's why you get an error.

The URL to reset your password should be `/password/reset`.

> Another thing, laravel documentation reads: To get started, verify that your App\User model implements the Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword contract.

Where does it say that? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication